# Extremely slow GPU memory allocation

Tags: nvidia, python, cuda

I'm having a problem with extremely slow memory allocation on an nvidia GPU from Python.

When running a GPU calculation in a fresh Python session, tensorflow/pytorch allocates memory in tiny increments for around four minutes until it suddenly allocates a large chunk of memory and performs the actual calculation. All subsequent calculations are performed instantly.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Or how to get a log of what is actually going on during memory allocation?

I've tried re-installing CUDA libraries and nvidia drivers. Re-installing drivers fixes the issue for a little while, then memory allocation hangs again.

**Python output:**

```
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:06) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('import tensorflow as tf;tf.random.uniform([10])', number=1)
2023-04-17 09:08:24.062130: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-17 09:08:24.641429: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-04-17 09:12:12.879503: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21368 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: GRID RTX6000-24Q, pci bus id: 0000:02:02.0, compute capability: 7.5
229.68861908599501
```

**nvidia-smi:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.182.03   Driver Version: 470.182.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID RTX6000-24Q    On   | 00000000:02:02.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   N/A    P8    N/A /  N/A |  23527MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    122079      C   ...Model-js4zUkog/bin/python    21743MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**nvcc:**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *lunar* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 April 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *lunar* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)  *Details in your provided pastes only match unsupported Ubuntu*

Comment: @guiverc Good to know, my question is not about Ubuntu Lunar though.

Comment: python3 or `python3 | 3.11.2-1` is only default for Ubuntu 23.04 (until recent release being Ubuntu *lunar*), and that is the only release details I noted in your question - ie. details from pasted detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that slow memory allocation was caused by nvidia throttling my GPU because the license could not be verified.

I checked:

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep nvidia`

And found:

`Apr 18 11:35:43 srv-apu102 nvidia-gridd: Valid GRID license not found. GPU features and performance are restricted. To enable full functionality please configure licensing details. Apr 18 11:42:32 srv-apu102 nvidia-gridd: Acquiring license. (Info: http://10.1.2.56:7070/request; NVIDIA RTX Virtual Workstation) Apr 18 11:42:32 srv-apu102 nvidia-gridd: Calling load_byte_array(tra) Apr 18 11:42:35 srv-apu102 nvidia-gridd: Error: Failed server communication. Server URL : http://10.1.2.56:7070/request - #012[1,7e2,2,0[74000008,7,110001f3]] Generic communications error.#012[1,7e2,2,0[75000001,7,30010255]] General data transfer failure. Couldn't connect to server`

I hope this helps others, regardless of the downvotes from people who seems to think that my question is about Ubuntu Lunar...